# angular ng-options not working anymore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

well i am using ng-options to for my selectbox (in jade) like this

```
select.form-control(ng-model="newSector", ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in sectors")
```

everything worked fine so far. but now (no idea why). newSector is not set with an value anymore, althougth the selectbox looks fine (all options are visible), but $scope.newSector is always undefined.

does anyone got a clue what's wrong. I recently updated the angular ui from 0.4 to 0.6, but that should not affect a angular.js feature (i use angualar 1.1.5 btw)

EDIT:

I think this got something to do with the angular-ui $modal element and scopes. because if i run this form without that $modal it is working, but when i run this form with this $modal its not working.

Comment: That function call looks a bit strange. I couldn't find a proper documentation for that function, can you point one? BTW, looks like you are trying to use keyword arguments, that don't work in javascript.

Comment: maybe it's `jade` template?

Comment: yes its jade (in html <select class="form-control" ng-model="newSector" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in sectors"></select> )

Comment: Can you put an ng-change function on the select and try to log the value on newSector model?

Comment: i added a ng-change event and it gets triggered when i changed the selected Item, but the value of newSector is always null. Another weird thing is that when i check the dom, the options tags look all fine, the value contains an ID and the text is also correct